# Is there a way to create a new column and assign values based on criteria on an existing column in a SQL query?

Tags: sql

I want to create a new column in my query output and assign values to it based on existing columns in my input. Let's say i have column A in my input and want to create column B in my query output. How do I add the following logic in a sql select statement?

If A = 1 then set B to x

Else if A = 2 then set B to y

Else if A = 3 then set B to z

Else set B to null

I have to do this for multiple new columns in my output within the same query.

Answer (score 2):

This is a `case` expression:

```
select . . .,
       (case A when 1 then 'x' when 2 then 'y' when 3 then 'z' end) as b
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT A,
CASE
  WHEN A = 1 THEN 'x'
  WHEN A = 2 THEN 'y'
  ELSE 'z'
END AS B
FROM ...
```